# How to use Siri to initiate AirPlay

Tags: siri, airplay, homepod

Today’s press release from Apple regarding version 17 of the HomePod software says:

> Siri support for AirPlay allows you to start an AirPlay session from your iPhone or iPad directly on your HomePod using just your voice, so you can play an even wider range of third-party music services on HomePod.

How does that work? What is the verbal command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not only a single command for this, there are many variations of a "base command": "*Hey, Siri. Play music on appName*".

There is actually a [WWDC 23 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10104/?time=108) that explains this in detail. Basically, Siri (on the HomePod) will use your iPhone to automatically play what you have requested via AirPlay. But here is  schema from the video to sum it up:

[image: Screenshot taken from the video linked above describing how Siri AirPlay works with HomePod on iOS 17]

The video also contains many more Siri commands you can use. Here are some of them:

[image]